# json - requests.get() params 'Too many values to unpack'

Tags: python, json, parameters, python-requests

I am working to create a custom COVID dataframe. I would like to return only specific parameters. The below is my code.

```
import requests

params = {'Date','Deaths'}
resp = requests.get('https://api.covid19api.com/country/canada', params=params)
jsonResponse = resp.json()
print(jsonResponse)
```

The result I expect would be just the date and death information, for all available dates.

However, it returns the error 'too many values to unpack (expected 2)'.

Would you please suggest how I might get the desired response?

Edit: I'm not looking for the instance of a specific key value pair (e.g. when Deaths = 27, which I understand would be coded as
`params = {'Deaths':'27'}`. Rather, I only want to extract the date and deaths keys, with all associated values to get the following:

2020-03-22T00:00:00Z, 20

2020-03-23T00:00:00Z, 27

2020-03-24T00:00:00Z, 31
...

Is there a way to specify this when the API is called, or do I need to retrieve all information in the API first, and then filter for 'Date' and 'Deaths'?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `{'Date', 'Deaths'}` => `{'Date': 'Deaths'}`, should be 2 dot, if not that is a `set`

Comment: If you read the stacktrace, you can see that it is relate to the params, then you look your code and see it ;)

Comment: We are not the developers API, we don't know it, you have to look by yourself about the service the API provides

Answer (score 1):

you have to define params as {"key": "value"}.

Comment: That is a typo, don't answer to such please

Comment: @azro he's declaring a set instead of a dictionary and that's why he's seeing that error.

Comment: Yes saw that, but that is just a typo error, that is surely not volunteer

Comment: @azro what's your problem if others want to answer?

Comment: @gravetii at least a nice answer with the correct code for the OP. And that's the rules of SO , there is flag optino that is "typo error" that's pretty explicit that typos errors should be closed for that

Comment: @azro are you talking about the question or this answer?

Comment: @gravetii question has a typo and shoudn't be answers. That answer is poor quality as the error is not explained, and correction code could be provided